# Recursive find optimisation

Tags: c++, recursion

I am new to c++ and want to solve a recursive find problem 
such that the input starts with an integer T (T ≤ 100), the number of test cases.
Each of the next 2*T lines will start with an integer N (1 <= N <= 100), a number of integers followed by N-space separated. Each of these N integers will be between -1000 and 1000 (inclusive).Then next line will have X (-1000 <= X <= 1000) representing the number you want to search for.
for example

**Input:**

**2**

**5 5 13 -11 19 93**

**-19**

**3 15 65 -18**

**-18**

The output should be

**Case 1: NO**

**Case 2: YES**

My code to solve the problem is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
bool find(int values[],int x,int i);
int main(){
        int  n, len,x ;
        cin >> n;
        std::ostringstream oss;
        for(int i =1;i<=n;i++){
                cin >> len;
                int values [len];
                for (int j =0;j<len;j++){
                        cin >> values[i];
                }
                cin>>x;

                oss<< "Case "<< i << ": " << (find(values,x, (len-1))?"YES":"NO") << "\n";
        }
        cout << oss.str() << endl;
        return 0;
}

bool find(int values [],int x, int i){
        if(values[i] ==x)
                return true;
        else{
                if(i ==0)
                        return false;
                return find(values,x,i-1);
        }
}
```

The code runs fine on my device, however, when submitted it causes a segmentation fault.
Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Obvious optimization: make it non-recursive, and just use `std::find`! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're iterating over the number of test cases with the variable *i*, but you're using that variable to read in integers to some index in your array as well. You should instead use the variable *j* to read integers into your array.

Change

```
for (int j = 0; j < len; j++){
    cin >> values[i];
}
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    cin >> values[j];
}
```

Comment: And to expand: If i is >= len, you write beyond the allocated limits of the values array and induce undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, will improve my variable naming to differentiate between them :)

Comment: Your variable naming is fine. Looks like you simply hit the i key instead of the j.